# Bizarre IE8 error when using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I am getting a weird error in IE8 only, not in IE9. The error message is:

> SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number

Here is my markup:

```
<style>
    .warrior { color: red; }
    .ninja  { color: blue; }
    .wizard { color: green; }
</style>

<div id="player"></div>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    (function () { 
        "use strict"; 

        var joeBlow = {
            name: "Joe Blow",
            class: "ninja", 
            age: 35
        };
        $("#player").html(joeBlow.name + " " + joeBlow.age).addClass(joeBlow.class);
    }());
</script>
```

My expectation is that the `DIV` will have "Joe Blow 35" written in blue, but I am receiving the error above.

What is causing this to happen in IE8, but not IE9 or IE10?

Comment: `class` is a reserved word, it may be that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`class` is a reserved keyword. Put quotes around it `'class'`. You may also have to access the  property using the `[]` notation as in `joeBlow['class']`.

Comment: Note that in this context (object property name) it should not be a problem in ES5 compliant browsers (which IE8 is not).

Comment: @bfavaretto - oh wow, so `class` is not a reserved word in ES5 and later? Good to know. :-)

Comment: @Karl It is a reserved word, but reserved words apply to variable and function names, not property names.

Answer (score 2):

As plalx explained, you'll have to quote `class` and use bracket notation for IE 8 to support using it as a property name since it's a reserved word.

```
var joeBlow = {
    name: "Joe Blow",
    'class': "ninja", 
    age: 35
};
$("#player").html(/* ... */).addClass(joeBlow['class']);
```

Or, use another name for the property. (Note: This is the option W3C chose for [`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.className).)

But, to explain further as to why:

It's due to a difference in the standards being used. Specifically, IE 8 implements ECMAScript 3 while IE 9 and 10 implement [ECMAScript 5](http://es5.github.io/#x7.6).

And, between those editions of ECMAScript, the syntax for [Object initialisers](http://es5.github.io/#x11.1.5) and [dot notation](http://es5.github.io/#x11.2.1) changed to allow any [*IdentifierNames*](http://es5.github.io/#x7.6) (ES5), which include *ReservedWords*, rather than limiting them to just *Identifiers* (ES3).

> *Identifier* ::
>   *IdentifierName* **but not** *ReservedWord*

Comment: Wow, so there is even a difference between identifiers and identifier names in ES5? It is amazing that anything runs in JavaScript ever, let alone cross-browser or cross-versions. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @KarlAnderson Well, *Identifiers* and *IdentifierNames* are in both editions and have the same definitions. Just which can be used in certain contexts changed.